# laravel filtrar resultados por rango de fechas

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Hola necesito filtrar deacuerdo a un rango de fechas en particular estoy intentanto hacerlo por mi cuenta pero no ha salido bien me esta dando este error.
Quiero hacer el filtro por el campo Fecha_emision mas abajo esta el modelo de mi tabla

```
"SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 7 ERROR:  la sintaxis de entrada no es válida para tipo date: «» (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from "presupuesto" as "p" inner join "users" as "u" on "p"."cod_usuario" = "u"."id" inner join "cliente" as "c" on "p"."cod_cliente" = "c"."codigo_cliente" inner join "contacto" as "co" on "p"."cod_contacto" = "co"."idcontacto" where "fecha_emision" between  and  or "c"."empresa" LIKE %% or "u"."name" LIKE %% or "p"."status" LIKE %% or "co"."nombre" LIKE %%)"
```

Mi Controlador:

```html
 public function index(Request $request){
 $request->fechaInicial;
        $request->fechaFinal;

        $date = date('Y-m-d');
    

    

if($request->fechaInicial == NULL || $request->fechaFinal == NULL){

  $f1 = $date;
  $f2 = $date;

}else{

$f1 = $request->fechaInicial;
    $f2 = $request->fechaFinal;


}





  if($request){
        $query=trim($request->get('searchText'));
        $f1=trim($request->get('f1'));
        $f2=trim($request->get('f2'));
        $ingreso=DB::table('presupuesto as p')
        ->join('users as u','p.cod_usuario','=','u.id')
        ->join('cliente as c','p.cod_cliente','=','c.codigo_cliente')
        ->join('contacto as co','p.cod_contacto','=','co.idcontacto')
        ->select('p.id', 'p.codigo_presupuesto','c.empresa','co.nombre','u.name','u.role','p.fecha_emision','p.fecha_expiracion','p.total', 'p.status', 'p.respaldo')
         ->whereBetween('fecha_emision', [$f1, $f2])
        ->orwhere('c.empresa','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')
                 ->orwhere ('u.name','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')
                        ->orwhere ('p.status','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')
                             ->orwhere ('co.nombre','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')
                               
        ->orderBy('p.id','desc')
        ->paginate(7);
        return view('ventas.presupuesto.index',["ingresos"=>$ingreso,"searchText"=>$query,"f1"=>$f1,"f2"=>$f2]);
      }
    }
```

Esta es mi Vista

```html
{!! Form::open(array('url'=>'ventas/presupuesto', 'method'=>'GET', 'autcomplete'=>'off', 'role'=>'search'))!!}
<div class="form-group">
 <div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="searchText" placeholder="Buscar" value="{{$searchText}}">
   <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-xs-12">
          <div class="form-group"> 
        <label class="control-label" for="date">Fecha De Emision</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="fechaInicial" name="fechaInicial"  placeholder="AA/MM/DD" value="{{$f1}}" type="text"/>
      </div>
         </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-xs-12">
          <div class="form-group"> 
        <label class="control-label" for="date">Fecha De Expiracion</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="fechaFinal" name="fechaFinal" placeholder="AA/MM/DD" value="{{$f2}}" type="text"/>
      </div>
         </div>
  <span class="input-group-btn"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Buscar</button></span>
 </div>
</div>
 @push ('scripts') <!-- Trabajar con el script definido en el layout-->
  <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
      var date_input=$('input[name="fechaInicial"]');
      var date_inputt=$('input[name="fechaFinal"]');  //our date input has the name "date"
      var container=$('.bootstrap-iso form').length>0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
      var options={
        format: 'yyyy/mm/dd',
        container: container,
        todayHighlight: true,
        autoclose: true,
      };
      date_input.datepicker(options);
        date_inputt.datepicker(options);
    })

    </script>
  @endpush
{{Form::close()}}
```

```html
@extends ('layouts.admin')
@section ('contenido')
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
   <h3>Listado de Presupuestos <a href="/ventas/presupuesto/create"><button class="btn btn-success">Nuevo</button></a></h3>
   @include('ventas.presupuesto.search')
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
   <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
     <thead>
      <th>Codigo Presupuesto</th>
      <th>Empresa</th>
      <th>Contacto</th>
      <th>Usuario</th>
      <th>Rol</th>
      <th>Fecha Emision</th>
      <th>Fecha Expiracion</th>
      <th>Total</th>
      <th>Estado</th>
      <th>Opciones</th>
     </thead>
     <!-- bucle -->
       
     @foreach ($ingresos as $ing)
     <tr>
      <td>{{$ing->codigo_presupuesto}}</td>
      <td>{{$ing->empresa}}</td>
      <td>{{$ing->nombre}}</td>
      <td>{{$ing->name}}</td>
      <td>{{$ing->role}}</td>
      <td>{{$ing->fecha_emision}}</td>
      <td>{{$ing->fecha_expiracion}}</td>
      <td>{{$ing->total}}</td>
      <td>{{$ing->status}}</td>
      <td>
         <a href="{{URL::action('PresupuestoController@edit',$ing->id)}}"><button class="btn btn-info">Editar</button></a>
       <a href="{{URL::action('PresupuestoController@show', $ing->id)}}"><button class="btn btn-info"> Detalles</button></a>
           <a href="/archivos/respaldoLegal/{{$ing->respaldo}}" download="{{$ing->respaldo}}">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
        <i class="glyphicon">
         Descargar
        </i>
        </button>
       </a>
         <a href="" data-target="#modal-delete-{{$ing->id}}" data-toggle="modal"><button class="btn btn-danger"> Anular</button></a> 
      </td>

      <td>

       
      
     </tr>
     @include('ventas.presupuesto.modal')
     @endforeach
     
    </table>
    
   </div>
   {{$ingresos->render()}}
   
  </div>
 </div>
@endsection
```

Cuando abro mi vista index me muestra todos los presupuestos creados, tengo la opcion de filtrar los registros ya sea por la empresa el contacto etc. pero tambien quisiera saber por ejemplo que me traiga todos los presupuesto donde su fecha de emision sea entre 2017-06-06 y 2017-06-18, lo que requiero es eso un filtro de fechas no se si me hago entender. pero si que me ha costado tratar de hacerlo
[image]

esto es loque encontre 
Se esperaba ':', pero se encontró '='.  Declaración rechazada.  presupuesto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor agrega el código del controlador o donde estés generando la consulta.

Comment: gracias lo olvide

Comment: ¿puedes mostrarnos los valores exactos que recibe `$request->fechaFinal` y `$request->fechaInicial`?

Comment: fechaInicial "2017-06-06" fechaFinal "2017-06-07"

Comment: Tengo otra duda, primero asignas las fechas a $f1 y $f2, pero después reasignas otros valores del reques a esas variables:        `$f1=trim($request->get('f1'));` ¿qué contienen dichos campos? El error de Postgres dice que no hay nada en la fecha, y por eso no coincide con el formato "date".

Comment: gracias por responder, la verdad estoy bien confudido de como hacer esto, tengo en el formulario son 2 calendarios name="fechaInicial" value="{{$f1}}" y name="fechaFinal"  value="{{$f2}}" , he inicializado las variables deacuerdo al formato YYYY-MM-DD y sigo con el problema  lo unico q quiero es filtrar los datos por el campo fecha_emision utilizando los calendarios

Answer (score 1):

Estás confundiendo como debes pasar las variables entre servidor y cliente.

En la vista podrías tener algo así, usando el helper `old()` para mostrar el dato anterior:

```
<input class="form-control" id="fechaInicial" name="fechaInicial"  placeholder="AA/MM/DD" value="{{ old('fechaInicial') }}" type="text"/>
```

---

En el controlador, en un punto estás intentando obtener dos variables f1 y f2 del request, las cuales por lo que veo, no existen. Deberías utilizar simplemente los valores que ya obtuviste antes.

Aquí el código, con un poco de refactoring, hay muchas cosas que sobran, especialmente el condicional del request, pues siempre existirá un Request en Laravel, no sé qué es lo que deseas comparar o verificar ahí:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    // eliminamos validaciones innecesarias y ponemos la fecha de hoy por defecto en ambas variables
    $f1 = $f2 = date('Y-m-d');

    if(! is_null($request->fechaInicial) && ! empty($request->fechaInicial) && ! is_null($request->fechaFinal) || ! empty($request->fechaFinal) {
        $f1 = $request->fechaInicial;
        $f2 = $request->fechaFinal;
    }

    // if($request){

        // no es necesario el trim si se utiliza el middleware correcto
        $query = trim($request->get('searchText'));

        // esto se puede hacer mejor con Eloquent
        $ingreso = DB::table('presupuesto as p')
            ->join('users as u','p.cod_usuario','=','u.id')
            ->join('cliente as c','p.cod_cliente','=','c.codigo_cliente')
            ->join('contacto as co','p.cod_contacto','=','co.idcontacto')
            ->select('p.id', 'p.codigo_presupuesto','c.empresa','co.nombre','u.name','u.role','p.fecha_emision','p.fecha_expiracion','p.total', 'p.status', 'p.respaldo')
            ->whereBetween('fecha_emision', [$f1, $f2])
            ->orwhere('c.empresa','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')
            ->orwhere ('u.name','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')
            ->orwhere ('p.status','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')
            ->orwhere ('co.nombre','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')                
            ->orderBy('p.id','desc')
            ->paginate(7);

        return view('ventas.presupuesto.index',["ingresos" => $ingreso, "searchText" => $query,"f1" => $f1, "f2" => $f2]);

    // }
}
```

Comment: gracias por tu tiempo, ya no me marca error pero no esta haciendo el filtro cadena consultada : searchText: "" fechaInicial: "2023-03-07" fechaFinal: "2023-03-01" no deberia mostrarme nada ya q solo tengo registrado estas fechas 2017-06-16 2017-06-06  2017-06-07

Comment: Probablemente haya algún error de apreciación de mi parte, puede ser que la comparación que haces con NULL sea incorrecta, tal vez puedes validar con empty() o is_null(), dependiendo de lo que desees hacer.

Comment: :S nada aun no he logrado hacer que funcione

Comment: Tendrías que explicarme exactamente y con mucho más detalle el contexto de lo que pretendes hacer en TODO el método index().

Comment: gracias por responder amigo, acabo de agregar una imagen con la descripcion de lo que quiero realizar

Comment: hello ayuda pls  :S

Comment: Hice una pequeña modificación en la validación a ver si mejora un poco, todavía no entiendo bien algunas cosas. Si no funciona, por favor me explicas de nuevo cuál es el comportamiento deseado.

Comment: hola esto es lo que necesito https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bv9XrpmdopI

Comment: ¿qué es lo que no funciona ahora? ¿qué datos aparecen?

Comment: no hace el filtro queda igual asi meta una fecha errada

Comment: Realmente necesito mucha más información de depuración para entender lo que está pasando, algo como las fechas o los valores que estén llegando antes de la consulta.

Comment: agregue una imagen al final de lo que ocurre tambien me sale esto Se esperaba ':', pero se encontró '='.  Declaración rechazada.  presupuesto

Comment: No entiendo de qué hablas, por favor ten en cuenta que yo no conozco tu proyecto ni tengo acceso al servidor o al código completo para entender el contexto. Lo que te estoy pidiendo puntualmente es información de depuración, la imagen que pusiste lastimosamente no me ayuda mucho.

Comment: ah ok me dices como puedo conseguir esa informacion